# Minkowski Penrose diagrams - what does the "past lightlike infinity" represent?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, causality

In a Minkowski Penrose diagram (see below), emitted light rays are always shown at a +45 degree angle, and eventually reach the "future lightlike infinity" line (note : in all of the following, "lightlike" can be replaced by "null").  But no one (and I've done a lot of searching) describes what the "past lightlike infinity" line represents, other than sometimes to say that it's where "incoming" light rays **end up** (analogous to the "future lightlike infinity" line), and *no one* defines what "incoming" means. And to *get* to that line (which means they travel at -45 degrees), they would have to be traveling backwards in time (down = back in time, right = forward in space)!

After much thought, I finally came up with this interpretation : light rays traveling toward r=0 (is there any reason there cannot be such photons?) must travel at a -45 degree angle *upwards* (so, 135 degrees?), and can be emitted at any point in the past.  So the "past lightlike infinity" line merely represents the furthest time in the past that such a light beam can be emitted.

Can someone please give a clear English description (not mathematical definition) of what the "past lightlike infinity" line **actually** represents (in a way that makes sense) and/or comment on my interpretation?  For bonus points, can you describe what an "incoming photon" means?

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused why do you think no one defines past null infinity. Indeed, start with spherical coords $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ and define $u=t-r$ and $v=t+r$. Lines of constant $u$ are outgoing null geodesics because their tangent vectors are future directed (increasing $r$ gets you to the future). Likewise lines of constant $v$ are incoming null geodesics because their tangent vectors are past directed (increasing $r$ gets you to the past). In any case, in the chart $(u,v,\theta,\phi)$, $v\to \infty$ defines ${\cal I}^+$ and $u\to -\infty$ defines ${\cal I}^-$. They are both there.

Comment: You could give me a similar definition of the future null infinity, but that doesn't tell me what it *represents* : the future null infinity is where all 45 degree photons will end up in the far future.  Can you describe what the past null infinity represents in an English statement?  But thanks, I'm going to change all my "define"'s in my OP to "describe".

Comment: It is where all incoming radial null geodesics have their past endpoints, i.e. where massless particles come from in the far past.

Comment: And that exactly matches my suggested interpretation in the OP, thanks!